# call stack missing info on mono with apache and mod_mono

Tags: asp.net, apache, debugging, mono, mod-mono

How do i enable debugging/stacktrace with filenames and numbers with apache2/mod_mono? Instead of filenames and numbers i get something like this

```
at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I tried using MonoDebug true in apache and recompile mod_mono with --enable-debug and i have `<compilation debug="true">` inside of `configuration>system.web>httpRuntime` in web.config.

i am using debian lenny and i tried installing mono-debugger, restart apache and still no luck. I even used the configuration tool with no luck. Many its only supported on suse? http://go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. There are quite few solutions. First of all, you MUST install mono-core-debuginfo package, or it might not work.

Second, you must run Mono in debug mode

*Solution 1:
Add this to your virtual host section/httpd.conf

```
MonoSetEnv MonoDebug true
```

*Solution 2:
Start xsp/mod-mono-server with debug

```
$ MONO_OPTIONS=--debug xsp2
```

Comment: Where is debuginfo ? i did this and not found it
# aptitude search mono | grep debug
p   libmono0-dbg                    - libraries for the Mono JIT, debugging symb
p   mono-dbg                        - Mono debugging symbols
p   mono-debugger                   - Debugger for Mono
p   mono-jit-dbg                    - fast CLI JIT/AOT compiler for Mono, debugg

Comment: Actually I use openSUSE: zypper in mono-core-debuginfo from Novell's official Mono repository. I don't know if those packages work for you, try them!

Comment: Still problems with that? Have you tried installing those debug symbols you found on aptitude? I found this link http://packages.debian.org/unstable/debug/libmono0-dbg, seems that the package is suitable for you.